# How can I choose which audio and subtitle tracks to keep when converting from MKV to MP4 with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-conversion, mkv

I have an .mkv file where there's 2 Audio tracks and 2 Subtitle tracks (SRT format).

I want to convert that .mkv to mp4 and have it have Audio track #2 and Sub track #2 as the ones to play when I launch the mp4.

[image]

I'm using FFMPEG, so I'm using this to convert:

```
ffmpeg -i myMovie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy myMovieMP4.mp4
```

This causes 2 issues:

1. It uses the Audio track #1

2. The subtitles don't appear even when the subtitle track is selected

*EDIT:
Results of ffmpeg -i test.mp4:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:22:59.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 362 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 90.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : Opening
    Chapter #0:1: start 90.400000, end 532.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part A
    Chapter #0:2: start 532.334000, end 1299.801000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part B
    Chapter #0:3: start 1299.801000, end 1359.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Ending
    Chapter #0:4: start 1359.334000, end 1379.754000
    Metadata:
      title           : Next on AAAA
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv, unknown/bt709/unknown), 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 326 kb/s, SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 30 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

*EDIT 2:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'myMovie.mkv':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2016-10-04T14:07:11.000000Z
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.0.100
  Duration: 00:22:59.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 388 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 90.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : Opening
    Chapter #0:1: start 90.400000, end 532.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part A
    Chapter #0:2: start 532.334000, end 1299.801000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part B
    Chapter #0:3: start 1299.801000, end 1359.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Ending
    Chapter #0:4: start 1359.334000, end 1379.754000
    Metadata:
      title           : Next on AAAA
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, unknown/bt709/unknown), 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Encoded with IFME v4.9.4.0
      BPS             : 326855
      BPS-eng         : 326855
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 33081
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 33081
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 56372607
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 56372607
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track 1
      BPS             : 29395
      BPS-eng         : 29395
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 5069783
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5069783
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Track 2
      BPS             : 30140
      BPS-eng         : 30140
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 5198254
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5198254
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Signs/Songs Sub
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.0.100 ass
      BPS             : 13
      BPS-eng         : 13
      DURATION        : 00:22:38.710000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:38.710000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 30
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 30
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 2313
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2313
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : Full English Sub
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.0.100 ass
      BPS             : 112
      BPS-eng         : 112
      DURATION        : 00:22:53.940000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:53.940000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 331
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 331
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 19247
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 19247
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Invalid input file index: 2.
```

*EDIT 3:
Using this command:

> ffmpeg -i myMovie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:s:1 -map 0:v:0
> -map 0:a:1 -c:s mov_text test.mp4

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'myMovie.mkv':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2016-10-04T14:07:11.000000Z
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.0.100
  Duration: 00:22:59.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 388 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 90.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : Opening
    Chapter #0:1: start 90.400000, end 532.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part A
    Chapter #0:2: start 532.334000, end 1299.801000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part B
    Chapter #0:3: start 1299.801000, end 1359.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Ending
    Chapter #0:4: start 1359.334000, end 1379.754000
    Metadata:
      title           : Next on AAAA
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, unknown/bt709/unknown), 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Encoded with IFME v4.9.4.0
      BPS             : 326855
      BPS-eng         : 326855
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 33081
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 33081
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 56372607
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 56372607
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track 1
      BPS             : 29395
      BPS-eng         : 29395
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 5069783
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5069783
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Track 2
      BPS             : 30140
      BPS-eng         : 30140
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 5198254
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5198254
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Signs/Songs Sub
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.0.100 ass
      BPS             : 13
      BPS-eng         : 13
      DURATION        : 00:22:38.710000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:38.710000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 30
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 30
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 2313
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 2313
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : Full English Sub
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.0.100 ass
      BPS             : 112
      BPS-eng         : 112
      DURATION        : 00:22:53.940000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:53.940000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 331
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 331
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 19247
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 19247
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 90.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : Opening
    Chapter #0:1: start 90.400000, end 532.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part A
    Chapter #0:2: start 532.334000, end 1299.801000
    Metadata:
      title           : Part B
    Chapter #0:3: start 1299.801000, end 1359.334000
    Metadata:
      title           : Ending
    Chapter #0:4: start 1359.334000, end 1379.754000
    Metadata:
      title           : Next on AAAA
    Stream #0:0(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874)
    Metadata:
      title           : Full English Sub
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 112
      BPS-eng         : 112
      DURATION        : 00:22:53.940000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:53.940000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 331
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 331
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 19247
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 19247
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mov_text
    Stream #0:1: Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv, unknown/bt709/unknown), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Encoded with IFME v4.9.4.0
      BPS             : 326855
      BPS-eng         : 326855
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 33081
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 33081
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 56372607
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 56372607
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Track 2
      BPS             : 30140
      BPS-eng         : 30140
      DURATION        : 00:22:59.755000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:59.755000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 32338
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 5198254
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5198254
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-10-04 14:07:11
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:0 (ass (ssa) -> mov_text (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=33081 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   61130kB time=00:22:59.74 bitrate= 363.0kbits/s speed=5.91e+03x
video:55051kB audio:5076kB subtitle:14kB other streams:0kB global headers:1kB muxing overhead: 1.644363%
```

Comment: Can you post in your question the results of: `ffmpeg -i myMovieMP4.mp4` ? This will guide the appropriate `-map` selection: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map

Comment: I added it what you requested to my post. I also had the time to play around and figured out how to at least get the right audio but can't get the subtitles to be native to the video.

Comment: Try `-map 2:s:1 -c:s mov_text`. This will be the 3rd stream (with video and audio being streams 1 and 2) and will select the 1st subtitle stream in your example.

Comment: I tried this:
ffmpeg -i myMovie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 2:s:1 -c:s mov_text test.mp4. I posted the result in my post. I get a "Invalid input file index: 2".

Comment: Oops! `-map 0:s:1` might hit the spot better

Comment: That's actually where I was at my latest point. I use this: 
ffmpeg -i myMovie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:s:1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -c:s mov_text test.mp4. It has the correct audio but the issue is that the subtitle is disabled by default and I can't get it to be imprinted on the video itself. I have to open the MP4 and then manually select "English Subs" in the Subs tracks. I'll post the log in a 3rd Edit in my post.

Comment: The map order is important: video first, then audio, then subtitles. But do you want to actually burn in the subtitles? The technique we are thrashing out creates a subtitle stream

Comment: I want the subtitles to appear on the video if I ever upload it somewhere (Youtube, etc.) or whenever it's launched. In that case I'm guessing I'd have to burn it in? I tried separating the .srt (subs file) and burning it onto the .mp4, but the subtitles become excessively big for no reason. I used ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mkv -map 0:s:1 input.srt to extract the SRT.

Answer (score 0):

MKVToolNix can list the number of the various streams, but can only output to mkv.

As a GUI for ffmpeg that can output to mp4, there is [dmMediaConverter](https://sites.google.com/site/dmsimpleapps/dmMediaConverter?authuser=0).

Very easy to use, but with subtitles I had to edit the subtitle codec and change to mov_text.

[image]

It can convert to various formats with all ffmpeg capabilities and limitations.